# Php Eclipse on windows azure

Tags: php, windows, eclipse, azure

After following all the steps:

- [Getting started with PHP on Windows Azure Tools for Eclipse](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2010/02/26/getting-started-with-php-on-windows-azure-tools-for-eclipse.aspx)
- [Easy Setup for PHP On Azure Development](http://www.joshholmes.com/blog/2010/04/13/easy-setup-for-php-on-azure-development/)

When I do "Run in developement fabric" nothing happens (the packaging must be failing).....

Help please

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no use of those 12 p's..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the Eclipse tooling is lacking support of the latest Windows Azure SDK. Solution is to roll back to Windows Azure SDK v1.1 and the Eclipse tooling will work again.

Other solution is to use the command-line packaging tools over at http://azurephptools.codeplex.com/

I do know when the next version of the tooling is coming out but I can't tell you legally. But do expect updated tooling in a "very near future".

Comment: Thanks for the info, argggggggg I wish this would be more advertised spent a lot of time trying to make it work :)